# What happens when only a few element from a list are from the same interface

Tags: java, list, loops, interface

Given I have this class:

```java
class Animal {
    void walk() { } 
    ....
    .... //other methods 
}
```

Coupled with the interface for animals who are able to chew:

```java
interface Chewable {
    void chew();
}
```

and have Reptile class implement this and not Birds (since Birds cannot chew) :

```
class Reptile extends Animal implements Chewable { }
```

and in case of Birds:

```
class Bird extends Animal { }
```

Here, reptiles and birds are both an interface of Animal.

If I had a case where I have to loop through a list of IAnimals, and call their chew() function, what will happen when there is a bird in the list ?

Comment: What happened when you tried to loop through a list of IAnimal and call their chew function?

Comment: I'd recommend you to read about how 'generics' works in Java. If you asking about iterating over ArrayList<Animal> or smth like. Also of course it is good to try it out!

Comment: So I tested myself, and got more or less confused.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `Animal` is not implementing the `Chewable` interface and therefore if you have a List of type `Animal` containing both Birds and Reptiles it will not have a `chew()` method. This is because the type `Animal` only "knows" of its own members and methods.

Comment: So in fact can Bird and Reptile be listed in the same list object ?

Comment: Correct, this is because both Bird and Reptile are also of type Animal since both extend the Animal class. This is an example of polymorphism and is explained into detail [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0xw06loTm1k)

Comment: Thank you, now everything is clear. Plus I just learned about instanceof and type cast, which are very usefull in that particular case.

Answer (score 0):

If you loop through a List of Animal (List), you could only call methods belonging to Animal. Therefore you can not call chew().

Comment: Thanks, I tested by myself and found out I was just on the tip of the iceberg